# display field before title node drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, field

I want to display the tag category of nodes before the title, the title field is unavailable in interface, is there a way to do that in node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php (I won't install another module like ds suite just for this purpose).
PS: I want to do this everywhere node is displayed.

Comment: In 2023 Drupal has the same problem :/   
There is no way to tweak where the title is going to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. In your page.tpl.php where your title is echoed wrap the title in an if statement to not display $title if you are in a node page e.g

```
    if(arg(0)!='node'):
      if ($title ): 
        print $title;
      endif; 
    endif; 
//print title only if i am not on node pages
```

1. and now you can `print $node->title` anywhere you like in your node.tpl.php

There other ways to do this in a custom module which sound more efficient, but if this is a single minor task, i guess editing your tpls is a good solution

Comment: I want to display the title but I want to display a tag term before it, I tried this but id doesn't work (maybe you'll figure what's wrong in it):   

`<?php if (!$page): ?>  

<?php if $content['field_name'] print render($content['field_name']); ?> /**I added this line before the title statement**/  

    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>`    

I want to get something like:

Category:
TITLE HERE

Content_body ...  
when category is a taxonomy term  

Any clue how to achieve this ?

Comment: Try printing just "TEST" where you want your variable to appear.  That way, if the "TEST" text actually works, you'll know you've got the correct template and correct spot, and the field you're trying to call is just not displaying for some reason... start simple at first!  Also, remember to flush your cache after making any template changes.

Comment: I did try to print a test text, it worked well so I should assume it's a variable error (maybe?) but I would get a php in this case no ?

Comment: No one can answer this please I am really stack here !

Answer (score 1):

The `$content` array only is available in `node.tpl.php`, whereas in `page.tpl.php` you have a `$page` array with already rendered children.